# How to log to console without clearing the user input line in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console

I am trying to find a way to have a node app where logging to the console and allowing user input is possible. That way I can have the console have logs while allowing the user to enter commands at the same time.

I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```
hello world
test
// <- new output would go here
> user input here
```

The way I want to do this is so that logging to the console would append to the console above the user input line, while keeping the user input line active. I have tried to create a solution with the following as well

```
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: "> ", // this also does not show up in the console for some reason, but its not that important
});

rl.on("line", (line) => { // makes user able to input into the console
  log(`Received: ${line}`);
});

setInterval(() => { // simulates console output
  log("Hello World");
}, 1000);

function log(str) {
  // process.stdout.cursorTo(x, y)
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0, -1); // have tried multiple different options of numbers/combinations
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.write(str);
}
```

But unfortunately, the console keeps clearing either the top line when y=-1, or the current line when y=0. This is not what I want. I want the current line to always be the input line and only show the user's input, while logging the logs into the lines above it. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries out there that handles drawing to screen. https://github.com/chjj/blessed. But if you want to use readline, you can probably do the math yourself kind of like this:

```
let lines = [];
const BOTTOM_ROW = 10;
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

rl.on('line', line => {
  log(`Received: ${line}`);
});

setInterval(() => {
  log('Hello World');
}, 1000);

function log(str) {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, 0);
  readline.clearScreenDown(process.stdout);
  lines.unshift(str);
  lines = lines.slice(0, BOTTOM_ROW);
  for (let row = 0; row < Math.min(BOTTOM_ROW, lines.length); row++) {
    process.stdout.write(lines[row]);
    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, row + 1);
  }
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdin, 0, BOTTOM_ROW);
}
```